# doctrine 2, cannot sortby

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

i cant sort my collection, i tried to sort the associated joined table by a field..

```
    $query = $this-em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from('\Entities\Users', 'u')
            ->leftJoin('u.comments', 'c')
            ->orderBy('c.feat', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('c.position', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();
```

my annotations for the users entities contains this for joining the comments table:

```
    /** @ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\Comments", mappedBy="discoverycategories")*/
protected $comments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the orderBy method doesnt accept a second parameter. But you have to put it like this instead

```
->orderBy('c.feat ASC')
->addOrderBy('c.position ASC')
```